# Vignette effect without coding

Tags: wpf, vignette

Is there any method exist to create vignetting/frame effect on picturebox, ie another picturebox with png image as overlay/mask? I don't want to see sharp edges between picture and background.

Comment: Image over image is the solution. I used PNG image below.

![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UsSV9.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [OpacityMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.opacitymask.aspx) : something like

```
   <Image Width="200" Source="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg">
      <Image.OpacityMask>
        <RadialGradientBrush>
          <GradientStop Offset="0.8" Color="#ffff"></GradientStop>
          <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#0fff"></GradientStop>
        </RadialGradientBrush>
      </Image.OpacityMask>
    </Image>
```

would give a vignette effect.